# Keras fit_generator and steps_per_epoch

Tags: deep-learning, keras

I've noticed that with `fit_generator`, the steps_per_epoch parameter is usually assigned `total_samples//batch_size`.

However if my total_samples is 1000 and my `batch_size = 32`, then it seems the 
I should have 31.25 batches, but I'm assigning only 31 batches per epoch.

Does this mean that I won't be able to train the incomplete batch?

I'm assuming the `shuffle` option would take care of this problem, 
but If I'm assuming a custom generator, would the `shuffle` option still work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you will be assigned only 31 steps here. What you need to do is to do is this:

```
numpy.ceil(total_samples//batch_size)
```

Since, the model can take any number of inputs so even the last batch is lesser than 32 it will work.

Comment: Ah. I thought my model was crashing because it was having trouble accepting a batch with samples less than batch-size. Going to have to retest. Thank you.

Comment: No I guess that's not the problem. Let me know if you get any errors.

Comment: Thanks. It seems to work. I think it was a problem with my custom generator that  was throwing that error.

Comment: `total_samples//batch_size` is integer division. You just need a single slash.

Comment: when we shuffle, how could we make sure that the entire training set is seen and used?